# Paging not working in Report Viewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I'm having an issue currently with the Report Viewer control.  My current project is an MVC3 app where I link in an aspx page with the Report Viewer control.  The page displays, however, I cannot page through the results at all.  Here is the code that I have.

Report.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Report.aspx.cs" Inherits="SOSNG.Reports.Report" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
        <title>Report Viewer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/Site.css"" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript><div class="noScript"><span class="errorMessage"></span>- This application works best with Javascript enabled.</div></noscript>
        <div class="page">

            <div id="MastHead">
                <div id="MastHeadLeft"></div>

                    <%--<h1 id="ApplicationName"><span class="Skip"></span></h1>--%>

                <div id="MastHeadRight"></div>

                <div id="MasterMenu" class="clear"> 
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="MainPalette">
                <div class="SubPalette"><h3 class="PaletteName"></h3>
                    <div class="SubPaletteContent">
                    <br />
                        <form id="form1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                            <div>
                                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="SOSNGReportViewer" runat="server" AsyncRendering="False" 
                                Height="100%" SizeToReportContent="False" Width="100%" ZoomPercent="100" 
                                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
                                     WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" 
                                     ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowParameterPrompts="false">

                                 </rsweb:ReportViewer>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Footer">
                <div id="FooterSpan"></div>
                <div id="FooterLeft"></div>
                <div id="FooterRight"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Report.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Report Type
            var reportType = (string)Session["ReportType"];

            //Search parameters
            var searchFBINumber = string.Empty;
            var searchVlanId = string.Empty;
            var searchNetworkDevice = string.Empty;
            var searchMACAddress = string.Empty;
            var searchLocation = string.Empty;
            var searchIPAddress = string.Empty;
            var searchComment = string.Empty;

            //Server Report setup
            var serverReport = SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport;
            serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"]);
            serverReport.ReportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDirectory"] + reportType;

            Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] RptParameters;

            //Switch on Report
            switch (reportType)
            {
                case "CommentReport":
                    searchComment = (string)Session["Comment"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchComment))
                    {
                        RptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
                        RptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("Comment", searchComment);

                        this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(RptParameters);
                        this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
                    }
                    break;
                case "FBINumberReport":
                    searchFBINumber = (string)Session["FBINumber"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFBINumber))
                        searchFBINumber = null;

                    RptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
                    RptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("FBINumber", searchFBINumber);

                    this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(RptParameters);
                    this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
                    break;
                case "IPAddressReport":
                    searchIPAddress = (string)Session["NetworkIPAddress"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchIPAddress))
                    {
                        RptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
                        RptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("IPAddress", searchIPAddress);

                        this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(RptParameters);
                        this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
                    }
                    break;
                case "LocationReport":
                    searchLocation = (string)Session["Location"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLocation))
                        searchLocation = null;

                    RptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
                    RptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("Location", searchLocation);

                    this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(RptParameters);
                    this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
                    break;
                case "MACAddressReport":
                    searchMACAddress = (string)Session["MACAddress"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchMACAddress))
                        searchMACAddress = null;

                    RptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
                    RptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("MACAddress", searchMACAddress);

                    this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(RptParameters);
                    this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
                    break;
                case "NetworkDeviceReport":
                    searchNetworkDevice = (string)Session["NetworkDevice"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNetworkDevice))
                        searchNetworkDevice = null;

                    RptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
                    RptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("NetworkDevice", searchNetworkDevice);

                    this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(RptParameters);
                    this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
                    break;
                case "VlanNumberReport":
                    searchVlanId = (string)Session["VlanId"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVlanId))
                    {
                        RptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
                        RptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("VlanId", searchVlanId);

                        this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(RptParameters);
                        this.SOSNGReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

[image: Report Viewer]

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean?  Is the paging not showing up, or you click it and nothing happens, or it gives a 404?

Comment: Any errors or 404s showing up in your server logs or IIS logs?

Comment: See my answer below.  The paging just didn't work.  When I clicked an arrow as shown in the image above, nothing happened.  I figured out that it was due that I wasn't checking for Post Back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to do a check on !IsPostBack at the beginning.  Each PostBack just rebinded the data and reset the control.  Should have known it was something simple.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered same issue a little while back.
Add this simple line of code to prevent postback and your pagination issue will be fixed.

> ```
> if (!IsPostBack){ //enter your report logic here }
> ```